# What is the essential difference between Document and Collectiction in YAML syntax?

Tags: yaml, format, metaprogramming, specifications, markup

Warning: This question is a more philosophical question than practical, but I find it well as to be asked and answered in practical contexts (forums like StackOverflow here, instead of the SoftwareEngineering stack-exchange website), due to the native development in the actual use de-facto of YAML and the way the way it's specification has evolved and features have been added to it over time. Let's ask:

As opposed to formats/languages/protocols such as JSON, the YAML format allows you (according to [this link](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#912-document-markers), that seems pretty official, or at least accurate and reliable source to understand the YAML specification) to embed multiple '`Documents`' within one file/stream, using the three-dashes marking ("`---`").
If so, it's hard to ignore the fact that the concept/model/idea of '`Document`' in YAML, is no longer an external definition, or "meta"-directive that helps the human/parser to organize multiple/distincted documents along each other (similar to the way file-systems defining the concept of "file" to organize different files, but each file in itself - does not necessarily recognize that it's a file, or that it's being part of a file system that wraps it, by definition, AFAIK.

However, when YAML allows for a multi-Document YAML files, that gather collections of `Document`s in a single YAML file (and perhaps in a way that is similar/analogous to HTTP Pipelining approach of HTTP protocol), the concept/model/idea/goal of `Document` receives a new, wider definition/character de-facto, as a part of the YAML grammar and it's produces, and not just of the YAML specification as an assistive concept or format description that helps to describe the specification.

**If so, being a `Document` part of the language itself, what is the added value of this data-structure, compared to the existing, familiar and well-used good old data-structure of `Collection` (array of items)?**

I'm asking it, because I've seen in this link ([here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#25-full-length-example)) some snippet (in the second example), which describes a YAML sequence that is actually a collection of logs. For some reason, the author of the example, chose to prefer to present each log as a separate "Document" (separated with three-dashes), gathered together in the same YAML sequence/file, instead of writing a file that has a "`Collection`" of logs represented with the data-type of array. Why did he choose to do this? Is his choice fit, correct, ideal?

I can speculate that the added value of the distinction between a Document and a Collection become relevant when using more advanced features of the YAML grammar, such as Anchors, Tags, References. I guess every Document provide a guarantee that all these identifiers will be a unique set, and there is no collision or duplicates among them. Am I right? And if so, is this the only advantage, or maybe there are any more justifications for the existence of these two pretty-similar data structures?

My best for now, is to see Document as a "meta"-Collection, that is more strict, and lack of high-level logic, or as two different layers of collection schemes. Is it correct, accurate way of view?

**And even if I am right, why in the above example (of the logs document from the link), when there's no use and not imply or expected to use duplications or collisions or even identifiers/anchors or compound structures at all - the author is still choosing to represent the collection's items as separate documents? Is this just not so successful selection of an example? Or maybe I'm missing something, and this is a redundancy in the specification, or an evolving syntactic-sugar due to practical needs?**

Because the example was written on a website that looks serious with official information written by professionals who dealt with the essence of the language and its definition, theory and philosophy behind (as opposed to practical uses in the wild), and also in light of other provided examples I have seen in it and the added value of them being meticulous, I prefer not to assume that the example is just simply imperfect/meticulous/fit, and that there may be a good reason to choose to write it this way over another, in the specific case exampled.

Comment: Interesting! Do you think this might be more relevant on [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). I'm not saying yes or no.

Comment: @radarbob I added a warning in the question's beginning, that may respond to your point.

Comment: P.S. The following may provide partial answer to my question: since Documents are subjected to a specific YAML Version, maybe it's possible to choose a different syntax-Version to each collected Document, allowing to plot YAML sequences of different syntax rules in the same file? Interesting. Yet I'm not sure it's even possible (maybe the Version declaration is limited to only-one per file/stream), nor am I sure it was intended even if possible.

Comment: P.S 2: maybe we can look at that, as analogue to the concept of "scope" in source-code, or as a "context". This meta-datatype provides a "sandboxed" structure with it's private "variables" (or "identifiers" in YAML's case), private links between items, not affecting other "contexts" (YAML documents). This is different from YAML Collections, in which every item of a Collection, affects the surroundings - takes unique keys, changes the ordering of items, the length, and other possible "functions" that calculate or process information within the document, that can't be cross-Document functions.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's look at the *technical* difference between the list of documents in a YAML stream and a YAML sequence (which is a collection of ordered items). For this, I'll discuss YAML tags, which are an advanced feature so I'll provide a quick overview:

YAML nodes can have tags, such as `!!str` (the *official* tag for string values) or `!dice` (a *local* tag that can be interpreted by your application but is unknown to others). This applies to all nodes: Scalars, mappings and sequences. Nodes that do not have such a tag set in the source will be assigned the non-specific tag `?`, except for quoted scalars which get `!` instead. These non-specific tags are later resolved to specific tags, thereby defining to which kind of data structure the node will be deserialized into.

YAML implementations in scripting languages, such as PyYAML, usually only implement resolution by looking at the node's value. For example, a scalar node containing `true` will become a boolean value, `42` will become an integer, and `droggeljug` will become a string.

YAML implementations for languages with static types, however, do this differently. For example, assume you deserialize your YAML into a Java class

```java
public class Config {
    String name;
    int count;
}
```

Assume the YAML is

```yaml
name: 42
count: five
```

The `42` will become a String despite the fact that it *looks* like a number. Likewise, `five` will generate an error because it is not a number; it won't be deserialized into a string. This means that not the content of the node defines how it will be deserialized, but the path to the node.

What does this have to do with documents? Well, [the YAML spec says](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#332-resolved-tags):

> Resolving the tag of a node must only depend on the following three parameters: (1) the non-specific tag of the node, (2) the path leading from the root to the node and (3) the content (and hence the kind) of the node.)

So, the technical difference is: If you put your data into a single document with a collection at the top, the YAML processor is allowed to take into account the position of the data in the top-level collection when resolving a tag. However, when you put your data in different documents, the YAML processor must not depend on the position of the document in the YAML stream for resolving the tag.

What does this mean in practice? It means that YAML documents are structurally disjoint from one another. Whether a YAML document is valid or not must not depend on any preceeding or succeeding documents. Consequentially, even when deserialization runs into a semantic problem (such as with the `five` above) in one document, a following document may still be deserialized successfully.

---

The goal of this design is to be able to concatenate arbitrary YAML documents together without altering their semantics: A middleware component may, without understanding the semantics of the YAML documents, collect multiple streams together or split up a single stream. As long as they are syntactically correct, stream splitting and merging are sound operations that do not invalidate a YAML document even if another document is structurally invalid.

This design primary focuses on sending and receiving data over networks. Of course, nowadays, YAML is primarily used as configuration language. This is why this feature is seldom used and of rather little importance.

---

**Edit:** (Reply to comment)

> What about end-cases like a string-tagged Document starts with a folded-string, making even its following "---" and "..." just a characters of the global string?

That is not the case, see rules [l-bare-document](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#rule-l-bare-document) and [c-forbidden](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#rule-c-forbidden). A line containing un-indented `...` not followed by non-whitespace will always end a document if one is open.

Moreover, `...` doesn't do anything if *no* document is open. This ensures that a stream merger can always append `...` to a document to ensure that the current document is closed, but no additional one is created.

`---` has widely been adopted as separator between YAML documents (and, perhaps more prominently, between YAML front matter and content in tools like Jekyll) where `...` would have been more appropriate, particularly in Jekyll. This gives the false impression that `---` should be used by tooling to separate documents, when in reality `...` is the syntactic element designed for that use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I'd love to ask about your epilogue. You say "a middleware may collect multiple streams, or split a single stream, without altering the semantics". Is it 100% true and always the case? What about end-cases like a string-tagged Document starts with a folded-string, making even its following "---" and "..." just a characters of the global string? In this case, I think that an external component will have to "read" the semantics and understand the situation. In addition, even heuristically separating documents with "---" may break the content in this example

Comment: @Reflection Edited to respond to your comment.

Comment: So in other words, you approve that the false convention of using --- is prone to this end-case error? And one should avoid it?

Comment: @Reflection Yes. `---` is a *directives end marker* and should be used when you have directives is the document, or for clarity when the root node is a scalar or has a tag. But never for ending a document, and I certainly prefer `...` between two documents when either is an option.